# automatically fill field in sharepoint edit forms

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have field that I want to automatize, I have department field is managed metadata, with different department, I want when I fill the editform, automatically , if department is IT then my field is NumIT0001 , the same for other department, have you any idea.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use a workflow. On item submitted the workflow would start, check the value of IT department and then use an if condition to set the required field.

Comment: But, i want during the user fill the formes, not after Save,

Comment: If I understand you trying to set some sort of ID correct? If yo udoing that on the form what happens when 2 people try to fill teh form at the same time? they will both get the same ID?

Comment: No, it will be two different id, because I have just one user per department who upload document, and during filling the form this user can have field filled automatically, by Numhisdept.